# Same column name in Pandas need to be removed

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe with same columnNames.I want to remove one particular repeated column.

In the below data frame, I want to remove all columns with Name **Numbers** and keep Alphabets. How could I achieve this

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Alphabets': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                     'Numbers': ['1', '2', '3'],
                      'Alphabets': ['D', 'E', 'F'],
                     'Numbers': ['10', '11', '12'],
                     'Alphabets': ['G', 'H', 'I'],
                     'Numbers': ['13', '14', '15']})
```

Comment: Down-voting as the question doesn't show any research effort. Consider searching for similar problems before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing any columns that match with a specific term, like this:

```
df= df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.match('Numbers')]
```

It will remove any columns that contains Numbers as names

Answer (score 2):

You can call the `.drop` method of `pd.DataFrame` and specify a list of columns you want to drop.

In your case that would be:

```py
data = data.drop(columns=['Numbers'])
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply this is just dropping the first column. I am reading data from excel so its adding Numbers.1, Numbers.2, Numbers.3 in data frame, not sure how to avoid this addition

Comment: You can specify multiple columns to drop, in your case `columns=['Numbers.1', 'Numbers.2', 'Numbers.3']`